# Set custom CsrfTokenGenerator in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, csrf, csrf-protection, symfony-3.4

I'm constructing an example in Symfony 3.4 that showcases how not to generate CSRF tokens (for educational purposes). I've made a custom `CsrfTokenGenerator` that implements the `TokenGeneratorInterface`, but now I would like to configure the `CsrfTokenManager` that's built-in in Symfony to use this generator for generating CSRF-tokens instead of the default one. How can I configure this in the Symfony yml-files? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

The `CsrfTokenManager` constructor has the following signature `public function __construct(TokenGeneratorInterface $generator = null, TokenStorageInterface $storage = null, $namespace = null)` and can thus take a custom `TokenGeneratorInterface` as a parameter, but how can I set this parameter, as we don't have direct access to this controller.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, this is a good one. There's no simple way of doing it. By simple way I mean overriding a config parameter.

In situations like these you make use of [Compiler Passes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html). Here is the way to go about it:

1. Register your implementation of `TokenGeneratorInterface` as a service.
2. Then, create and register a compiler pass. You can name it `CustomCsrfTokenGeneratorPass`. There are different ways of registering it depending if you are in a bundle or in your app.
3. In that compiler pass, you have access to the container builder. Use the `$container->findDefinition()` method to find the registered definition of the `CsrfTokenManager`.
4. Then modify the service definition by calling `$definition->setArgument()` on it. Replace the argument of your choice with a reference. `new Reference('your-custom-crsf-token-generator-service-id').
5. Enjoy.

Make sure to take a look to the compiler pass docs for more info.